# Refactoring legacy C code into MVC design

Tags: c++, c, model-view-controller

I am working on some OLD (as in older than me) C code that needs to be cleaned up and brought up to date so that (amongst other things), it is easier to maintain and integrates more cleanly with current code.

The existing code is quite messy, and freely intersperses GUI logic with business logic and data access logic. The only saving grace is that it is NOT spaghetti code, and that it is modular (as most code from the seventies tends to be).

My question is this: Can anyone provide me with a guideline on how to go about refactoring the code into MVC (BTW I am also moving the code from C to C++ whilst undertaking this task - but that is the least of my concerns, as I am quite aufait with both languages).

BTW, I am fully aware that this is not a trivial task. I just want to know what the steps are from going from modular code that mixes DBAL/BL/GUI to a cleaner MVC implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not convinced that there can be a definitive set of steps, what we do will vary with the structure of the existing code.

I agree with @Jesus Ramos that figuring out a test strategy is key here. The problem for you is likely to be that the code is currently not unit-testable, because there are effectively no "units", we can't test the business logic,say, without testing the UI.

I would give very serious consideration to rewriting the the thing rather than refactoring.

If you are going to refactor, then my guess is that you'll take a kind of "Swiss Cheese" approach. Drill out pieces, leaving a central mass with lots of holes. So pull out database access code, focusing on providing a clear API and set of Data Objects - these become the basis of your Model. Pull out the GUI code into a view layer. What's left is the Controller logic, which you can then refactor.

Answer (score 2):

I would build the business logic layer first (along with some unit tests to make sure it runs like the original), I would then work in the data layer (again along with unit tests). Once you have these two it's probably best to create an interface to allow the GUI code to be robust without being so coupled and expose the required functionality of business logic and data to the GUI although personally the GUI should only submit the data it has to the business logic layer and then that submits to the data layer. The key here is unit testing (if possible) as this will make your life easier to make sure that your code and the original are both the same functionally.

Again you don't have to follow this step by step it's just preference to leave the GUI until the end as that is less complicated (most of the time) than the business logic layer.

The most difficult task is figuring out the decoupling itself as some people make this difficult and just have all 3 layers in one single function and ripping that apart can be a hassle.